# Can the function be written without ";" in the end?

Tags: compilation-errors, command-line

I have seen the following code on the Internet:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(8,9);
void setup()
{
  mySerial.begin(9600);    
  Serial.begin(9600);   
  delay(100);
}
void loop()
{
  if (Serial.available()>0)
  mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  if (mySerial.available()>0)
  Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

The command works perfectly fine. How was it possible in the code to write the command without ";" at the end of the line?

The link to the code is: [enter link description here](https://roboindia.com/tutorials/send_receive_data_hc10_bluetooth)

Comment: take a coding course or read a book about C or C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you refer to this block?

```
if (Serial.available()>0)   <- here
mySerial.write(Serial.read());
if (mySerial.available()>0) <- here
Serial.write(mySerial.read());
```

If so, there *is* a `;` at the end of each command. The commands are just split onto two lines each.  It could be written like this:

```
if (Serial.available()>0) mySerial.write(Serial.read());
if (mySerial.available()>0) Serial.write(mySerial.read());
```

The second and fourth lines are the body of the `if`.  Better indenting with the original arrangement would be:

```
if (Serial.available()>0)
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
if (mySerial.available()>0)
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
```

Or even better, include the brackets around the body:

```
if (Serial.available()>0) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
}
if (mySerial.available()>0) {
    Serial.write(mySerial.read());
}
```

Comment: So this means, we are allowed to neglect the {} and () for conditions, right? But why do sometimes errors occur if I do not write this symbols?

Comment: You can omit the brackets if there is only one statement in the body of the if.

Comment: A conditional or loop expression, such as 'if' or 'while', controls the next statement or block. It does not need its own semicolon because it is not a complete complete statement. A block is one or more statements surrounded by '{' and '}' and is treated like a statement. So the following simple statement ended with ';' or block surronded by '{', '}' is a necessary part of the 'if' or 'while'.